# How can a program be configured for these steps?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, algorithm

Is it possible to create a program that implements sequential mathematical steps... in order to be circulated to more than one selected set?

Step 1: For the following sets:
$$S_1=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\},S_2=\{x_1,x_2,x_4\}$$

Step 2: Generate $A_1$ from $S_1$ such that:
$$A_1=x_1x_2x_3$$

Step 3: Find $S_1-S_2=x_3$
$$A_2=(1-x_3)x_1x_2x_4$$
Step 4: Find $$B=A_1+A_2=x_1x_2x_3+(1-x_3)x_1x_2x_4$$

Comment: Is this close enough to what you want? `S1={x1,x2,x3};S2={x1,x2,x4};
A1=Times@@S1;A2=(1-Times@@Complement[S1,S2])Times@@S2;B=A1+A2` which displays `x1 x2 x3+x1 x2 (1-x3) x4`  To explain `Times@@{list}` returns the product of the elements of the list and `Complement[list1,list2]` gives the elements of `list1` which are not elements of `list2` Mathematica sometimes sorts expressions based on the names of the elements. That is why the result is in a different order than you showed.

Comment: See [`An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language`](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/)